# Error running and compiling ParserDemo2

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to programatically generate dependency trees using the Stanford Parser, following the guide to running ParserDemo found at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml

I run the line:

```
java -mx200m -cp "stanford-parser.jar:." ParserDemo2 englishPCFG.ser.gz testsent.txt
```

which results in

```
 Could not find or load main class ParserDemo2
```

This makes sense, I need to compile, so I run

```
javac -cp "stanford-parser.jar:." ParserDemo2.java
```

which generates a .class file.

However, when I run it using the above line, I get:

```
java -mx200m -cp "stanford-parser.jar:." ParserDemo2 englishPCFG.ser.gz testsent.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.<clinit>(ParserGrammar.java:46)
    at ParserDemo2.main(ParserDemo2.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Something pretty basic?

Answer (score 0):

stanford-parser.jar, has dependency on other jars. You need to add them to classpath.

Comment: Ahh. How would I find out which jars those are?

Comment: The maven repo says, it has dependency on joda-time.jar, xom.jar, slf4j-api.jar etc. Refer https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.6.0/stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.pom and http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/faq.html

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote your answer as I do not have enough reputation...